# How to cite oneself as co-author without all names, for graduate school CV application?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, citations, application, cv

I saw someone posed similar question before, but I would like to know for biostatistics/clinical trials papers, if my name is listed in the 10th authors, how should I cite the work without mentioning everyone's name to save the space on CV for graduate school application?

*First author, second author, third author, my name, et al. "paper title" (1)*

or

*First author,..., my name, et al. "paper title" (2)*

What about if I am on the 3rd author, or 4th author, I feel like format (1) can't tell whether I am really on the 4th author or later author? Thanks.

Comment: In your field, how important is author position beyond *first*, possibly *early*, and *last*?

Answer (score 14):

There are two basic ways to do this, based on just how many names there are:

1. Choose a citation format that shows all the names, then highlight your own name with a bold or underline, e.g.:

   Skywalker, L., Solo, H., Kenobi, O., Jinn., Q, Amidala, P., Maul, D., Vader, D., **Binks, J.J.**, Palpatine, S. "High energy interventions from space facilities.", Journal of Space Combat, 1999.
2. Add an explicit note after the citation, e.g.:

   Skywalker, L., et al., "High energy interventions from space facilities.", Journal of Space Combat, 1999. **(Eigth author)**

The first will work for anything under a few dozen authors, if you have the patience, and is nice because it will also let you show the senior authors at the end of the list. The second works fine for short author lists too, but is also the only real option once you hit 100+ authors or where you are part of a named consortium.

Comment: Yes, these are the best options. I have also seen e.g. "8th author of 23" to give slightly more information.

Comment: An alternative is to not clarify at all. If the section is called (or you call it) "My papers" and then you do `Skywalker,L ,et al ."High...` an reader would understand that you are in the "et al" part, I'd say.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime So if the authors are Kathryn Janeway, Chakotay, Tuvok, Harry Kim, Tom Paris, Annika Hansen, Kes, and B'Elanna Torres, then Annika Hansen would be "7th author of 9"?